# Kakadu and Part 10 of the JPEG-2000 standard (JP3D)

Tags: compression, jpeg, jpeg2000

Does the [Kakadu software](https://kakadusoftware.com/) implement Part 10 of the JPEG 2000 standard,
also known as JP3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You only have access to MCT (Part 2), which would be the closest you can get to pseudo JP3D.

> Kakadu provides a comprehensive implementation of multiple parts of
>   the JPEG2000 family of standards:
>
> 1. Kakadu fully implements Part 1, — i.e., ISO/IEC 15444-1 (Core coding tools and JP2 file format)
> 2. Kakadu implements the vast majority of Part 2 — ISO/IEC 15444-2 (Extended coding tools and JPX file format)
> 3. Kakadu implements most of Part 3 — ISO/IEC 15444-3 (Motion JPEG 2000)
> 4. Kakadu implements almost all features of Part 9 — ISO/IEC 15444-9 (JPIP tools for interactive remote browsing)
> 5. Kakadu fully implements Part 15, — i.e., ISO/IEC 15444-15 (High Throughput JPEG 2000)

Reference

- https://kakadusoftware.com/demonstration/

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see my next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633505/kakadu-multi-component-transforms-on-volumetric-images