# Kakadu, Multi-component transforms on volumetric images

Tags: compression, jpeg2000

From [this](https://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Usage_Examples.txt) list of examples, it seems that Kakadu is able to compress volumetric images along the z-direction by leveraging the multi-component transform (Part 2) of the JPEG 2000 standard.

Specifically example (Aj). I tested it, it seems to work.

I tried to modify the example above for an image of 1024 x 1024 x 128 pixels,
I want to group slices in batches of 32 (or 64) and do a full DWT on the individual batches,
but I fail.

This is what I tried:

```
kdu_compress -i img.rawl\*128@2097152 -o img.jpx -jpx_layers \* \
              -jpx_space sLUM Creversible=yes Sdims="{1024,1024}" Clayers=4 \
              Mcomponents=32  Nsigned=no  Nprecision=12 \
              Sprecision=12,12,12,12,12,13  Ssigned=no,no,no,no,no,yes \
              Mvector_size:I4=32 Mvector_coeffs:I4=32 \
              Mstage_inputs:I25="{0,31}"  Mstage_outputs:I25="{0,31}" \
              Mstage_collections:I25="{32,32}" \
              Mstage_xforms:I25="{DWT,1,4,3,0}" \
              Mnum_stages=1  Mstages=25
```

It fails with this error message:

```
Kakadu Core Error:
Multi-component transform does not satisfy the constraints imposed by Part 2 of
the JPEG2000 standard.  The first transform stage must touch every codestream
image component (no more and no less), while subsequent stages must touch every
component produced by the previous stage.
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the fix?